# How to implement a search for surrounding suburbs or postal codes?

Tags: spring, google-maps-api-3, lucene

When user enters a suburbs name or postal code I need to find its surrounding suburbs or postal codes, I had a look at the following solutions that I have found in my researches, but none of them helped much any other solution?

```
1) Google Map >> limitations on number of requests
2) Geonames >> not precision
3) Lucene >> usually for data search not sure how to use for suburbs.
```

Comment: Have you read [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-spatial/)? It explains how geospatial search can be done using Lucene.

Comment: I would use Geonames for this type of search. I note your "not precision" comment but would add that all hierarchical classifications tend to be problematic with regard to cities and their suburbs. Firstly, not all cities have definitive boundaries in which case what's in and what's out? Secondly, it's quite usual for cities to have multiple systems of subdivision - eg traditional "town" names versus current administrative areas - it should be easy to appreciate that the two systems do not necessarily correspond with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes? to find surrounding postcodes.